# Ant: How to compile jar that includes source attachment

Tags: java, ant

How do I create a jar with Ant that includes the source attachment?

Maven does this, but I'm living maven-free since '03 (well, 2009, but it doesn't rhyme).

I can't see any options in the javac task which does this.

I tried including the source .java files in the fileset passed to the javac task, but this didn't work.  When I try to view the source through something like Eclipse, I still get the 'no source attachment' display.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need two things to make it work in Eclipse:

- Include the source files in the file set, so that each `.java` file exists in the same folder in the JAR as the corresponding `.class` file;
- In the `<javac>` task, add the following parameter: `debug="on"`. That way, you encode information into the `.class` files about the corresponding `.java` files that tools like Eclipse need in order to connect the two together.

Comment: An appreciation Haiku:  The debug option / How did I overlook this? / Grateful for your help.

Comment: Is there no more specific flag?  I would like to always deploy with source, but not in debug mode.

Comment: @Ben Easy: just package the source with your jar (or maybe in a separate one), and leave out the debug option. You won't be able to F3 into specific methods from Eclipse though, because that requires the debug info.

Comment: @jqno Tell me please, should I include `.java` files to the class folder if I use `srcdir` and `dstdir` attributes in combination with `debug=on` inside `<javac>` tag?